# Как внутренняя функция декоратора получает *args и **kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот для примера функция с декоратором

```py
from datetime import datetime

def add_log_info(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f'{datetime.now()}: Вызвана функция {func.__name__}')
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper

@add_log_info
def say_my_name(name):
    print(f'Your name in {name}')

say_my_name('Вася')
```

Я не могу понять как функция `wrapper` получает аргументы `*args` и `**kwargs`. В момент когда функция `say_my_name` передается в декоратор, она ведь еще не вызвана, насколько я понимаю мы как бы передаем саму функцию туда, само ее определение. Но тогда как вместе с ней передаются аргументы, которые в итоге передаются транзитом в вызов `func` из `wrapper`? Надеюсь, что мой вопрос понятен :)

Comment: Декоратор `@add_log_info` — это синтаксический сахар, аналогичный конструкции `say_my_name = add_log_info(say_my_name)`. Вы можете это легко проверить, выполнив `print(say_my_name)`, внутренне устройство после декорирования уже другое.

Comment: Даже в таком варианте это немного сложная для понимания концепция) Ок, мы переопределили `say_my_name`. Я правильно понимаю, что она как бы начинает принимать на вход при этом один явный позиционный аргумент (саму себя старую) и все остальное становится как бы *args и **kwargs? И когда мы вызываем потом декорированную функцию, мы как бы на самом деле вызываем `decorator_func(undecorate_func, *args, **kwargs)`?

Comment: А они (аргументы) вместе с ней и не передаются. Они передадутся самому wrapper-у. А враппер вызовет ту самую func (которая будет доступна через замыкание внутри  add_log_info ) и передаст ей эти аргументы. Тут даже нет особой магии, просто паттерн. Но да, не очень очевидный

Comment: Вся неочевидность из-за использования замыкания

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если говорить в терминах вашего примера, то после декорирования имя `say_my_name` обозначает уже не саму эту функцию, а `wrapper`. А сама эта функция теперь лежит внутри `wrapper` под именем `func`.

То есть когда вы делаете вызов этой функции, происходит следующее:

1. Вы вызываете `say_my_name('Вася')`
2. Так как теперь под этим именем уже не сама функция, а обертка вокруг неё, то происходит вызов этой обёртки (`wrapper`), а аргументы (в данном случае один аргумент `Вася`) передаются во `wrapper`.
3. Так как `wrapper` принимает `*args, **kwargs`, то у вас `args` становится списком `['Вася']`, а на `kwargs` уже никаких аргументов не осталось, это просто пустой словарь.
4. Внутри обёртки у вас дёргается функция `func`, которая является просто псевдонимом для того, что было первоначальной функцией `say_my_name`, но потеряло право так называться после декорирования.
5. В эту `func` передаются аргументы `*['Вася'], **{}` - то есть просто один позиционный аргумент `'Вася'`. А у нас `func` как раз и принимает один аргумент `name`. (Так как `func` - это же бывшая `say_my_name`)
6. Ну и в итоге этот аргумент у вас просто печатается на экран.